# Angular pre-bootstrap (first screen) loader's animation freezes during initial loading

Tags: angular

Simple demo here: https://plnkr.co/edit/IA0Bs5VH9WwVbLlKPQ6X?p=preview (I used the official angular.io/docs demo app)

**The problem** is: the first screen loader (I used loader.svg) animation freezes for a second during the initial loading of Angular App

The process goes like this: open the page, svg loader animation starts -> loader **animation freezes** -> loader animation re-starts -> angular app finish loading, loader hided

In this demo, the freeze is more obvious: http://iarouse.com/dist-angular2-material/v1/

```
<my-app>
  <!-- the loader -->
  <div id="loader-container"></div>
</my-app>
```

My real app is larger, and the initial loader animation freezes for a few seconds during bootstrap process, which is frustrating

Any thing I can do to make it smooth?

Comment: Is that AngularJS, Angular2 or Angular4? You put the 3 tags...

Comment: Hi @Mistalis, the demo uses angular 4, I used the official demo in angular.io docs

Comment: There is no Angular4 doc right now :( .. we all still waiting for it. Well made, seems like your application is not "non-blocking" optimized. Its not that easy to solve the problem due to many many limitations e.g. client performance.

Comment: Hi @AlexG, are you talking about a freeze before the spinner appears or between spinner fades out and application pop in ?

Comment: Hi @lin, the loader's animation freezes in angular2 app too, I think the angular version is not the problem here, the problem probably is my code

Comment: Hi @bviale, it's a freeze during the bootstrap process of angular app. The process goes like this: open the page, svg loader animation starts -> loader animation freezes -> loader animation re-start -> angular app finish loading, loader hided

Comment: Yea, it's not that easy create a non blocking init routine. You could handle it with nice codes, timeouts and small loading procedures. This "bug" is totally depending on your codes -> blocking.

Comment: @AlexG Don't use the `angularjs` tag. It is for **AngularJS** (1.x).

Comment: Hi @Mistalis, thanks for removing the `angularjs` tag, I thought it was `angular`

Comment: IMO you should be OK with a blocking loading routine because its nothing unknown in the world of "loading procedures". This happends to games, OS system -> lets say to all parts of software. I remember starting up Windows 95 on my P1 which was a freezing like northpole.

Comment: Hi @lin, the reason I ask this question is because I saw repos like https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin (it has a live demo), its first loader is smooth, I don't know why

Comment: @AlexG Application bootstrapping is a heavy operation, we cannot really control how to prevent the lag. Maybe try to change your SVG into a light CSS3 animation, it should go smoother

Comment: Hi @bviale, it's the same with CSS3 animation, I tried keyframe animation, it freezes too

Comment: @AlexG Don't forget that you are prototyping an application in your brower, with in-browser dependencies resolution and typescript compilation. You should not have lags in a "normal" application anyway

Comment: @AlexG Alright I saw your edit, and this problem appears with the code compiled in a clean way too

Comment: @bviale interestingly, I saw repos like github.com/akveo/ng2-admin (it has a live demo), its first loader is smooth, I don't know why, I am digging into its code now

Comment: @AlexG Maybe check if you have code in constructors, and move it to `onInit`. Also the dashboard seems to have been built with Ahead Of Time compilation, have you tried to add `--aot` flag to your build with angular cli ?

Comment: There is the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50162007/7251079) (solved)

Comment: @AlexG have you figured out the issue? I'm also getting same issue of freezing SVG animation on page load.

Comment: I've updated this with a bounty. Even css animations will freeze and the answers provided do not work. If there is a fancy splash animation with css it will freeze even further and looks unprofessional

Answer (score 0):

I had your problem because I was rendering a gif spinner image.
I tried the solution posted by @bviale and it worked.

Simply used the code founded in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp and putted between the `app-root` tag.

Comment: can you please explain about this solution? I'm also getting this issue that my SVG animation freezes on first load of page but after that goes smooth as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/IA0Bs5VH9WwVbLlKPQ6X?p=preview

If I put below script in the end after  ends then i see loader playing smoothly without interruption, because is see lots of errors on console.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

error sample I am talking about:

```
GET https://unpkg.com/core-js@3.6.5/client/shim.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

And after moving script after body, your index.html looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <title>Angular Tour of Heroes</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- Polyfills -->


    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>
      <div id="loader-container"></div>
    </my-app>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```