# How to prevent UI thread freezing when Angular app is being loaded?

Tags: angular, user-interface, browser

I have an animated loader (.svg or.gif) on my `index.html`. When I open the app, animation freezes after a few frames. Is there any workaround?

Comment: What is the animated loader made of? Is it a GIF image?

Comment: I tried gif and svg.

Comment: Try using css3 animations. Are you using aot?

Comment: @yurzui, .svg uses css for animation, doesn't it? No, I used JIT. It's a good idea to try AOT. Thank you.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201592/angular-pre-bootstrap-first-screen-loaders-animation-freezes-during-initial-l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UI thread freezes because of Angular app compiles at runtime in the *browser*. To avoid freezes use **Ahead-of-Time** (AOT), which compiles an app at build time.

Details at [Angular docs: The Ahead-of-Time (AOT) Compiler](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)