# Angular freeze SVG animation on initial loading screen

Tags: angular, svg, browser

I want to play an animation when browser is loading scripts and other assets of Angular 5.

For example this SVG animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Generator: SVG Circus (http://svgcircus.com) -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="SVG-Circus-fd09094d-ef46-ec99-9c7e-2ce68491a50b" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <rect id="actor_8" x="30" y="45" width="10" height="10" opacity="1" fill="rgba(242,162,12,1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(166,3,17,1)" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="">
    </rect>
    <rect id="actor_7" x="30" y="60" width="10" height="10" opacity="1" fill="rgba(242,162,12,1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(166,3,17,1)" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="">
    </rect>
    <rect id="actor_6" x="45" y="60" width="10" height="10" opacity="1" fill="rgba(242,162,12,1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(166,3,17,1)" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="">
    </rect>
    <rect id="actor_5" x="60" y="60" width="10" height="10" opacity="1" fill="rgba(242,162,12,1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(166,3,17,1)" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="">
    </rect>
    <rect id="actor_4" x="60" y="45" width="10" height="10" opacity="1" fill="rgba(242,162,12,1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(166,3,17,1)" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="">
    </rect>
    <rect id="actor_3" x="60" y="30" width="10" height="10" opacity="1" fill="rgba(242,162,12,1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(166,3,17,1)" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="">
    </rect>
    <rect id="actor_2" x="45" y="30" width="10" height="10" opacity="1" fill="rgba(242,162,12,1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(166,3,17,1)" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="">
    </rect>
    <rect id="actor_1" x="30" y="30" width="10" height="10" opacity="1" fill="rgba(242,162,12,1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(166,3,17,1)" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="">
    </rect>
    <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[(
        function()
        {
            var actors={};

            actors.actor_1=
            {
                node : document.getElementById("SVG-Circus-fd09094d-ef46-ec99-9c7e-2ce68491a50b").getElementById("actor_1"),
                type : "square",
                cx : 35,
                cy : 35,
                dx : 10,
                dy : 5,
                opacity : 1
            };

            actors.actor_2=
            {
                node:document.getElementById("SVG-Circus-fd09094d-ef46-ec99-9c7e-2ce68491a50b").getElementById("actor_2"),
                type : "square",
                cx : 50,
                cy : 35,
                dx : 10,
                dy : 5,
                opacity : 1
            };

            actors.actor_3=
            {
                node : document.getElementById("SVG-Circus-fd09094d-ef46-ec99-9c7e-2ce68491a50b").getElementById("actor_3"),
                type:"square",
                cx:65,
                cy:35,
                dx:10,
                dy:5,
                opacity:1
            };

            actors.actor_4=
            {
                node:document.getElementById("SVG-Circus-fd09094d-ef46-ec99-9c7e-2ce68491a50b").getElementById("actor_4"),
                type:"square",
                cx:65,
                cy:50,
                dx:10,
                dy:5,
                opacity:1
            };

            actors.actor_5=
            {
                node:document.getElementById("SVG-Circus-fd09094d-ef46-ec99-9c7e-2ce68491a50b").getElementById("actor_5"),
                type:"square",
                cx:65,
                cy:65,
                dx:10,
                dy:5,
                opacity:1
            };

            actors.actor_6=
            {
                node:document.getElementById("SVG-Circus-fd09094d-ef46-ec99-9c7e-2ce68491a50b").getElementById("actor_6"),
                type:"square",
                cx:50,
                cy:65,
                dx:10,
                dy:5,
                opacity:1
            };

            actors.actor_7=
            {
                node:document.getElementById("SVG-Circus-fd09094d-ef46-ec99-9c7e-2ce68491a50b").getElementById("actor_7"),
                type:"square",
                cx:35,
                cy:65,
                dx:10,
                dy:5,
                opacity:1
            };

            actors.actor_8=
            {
                node:document.getElementById("SVG-Circus-fd09094d-ef46-ec99-9c7e-2ce68491a50b").getElementById("actor_8"),
                type:"square",
                cx:35,
                cy:50,
                dx:10,
                dy:5,
                opacity:1
            };

            var tricks={};

            tricks.trick_1=
            (
                function(t,i)
                {
                    i=
                    (
                        function(t)
                        {
                            return Math.sqrt(1-(t-=1)*t)
                        }
                    )(i) % 1, i = 0 > i ? 1 + i : i;

                    var _ = t.node;0.2 >= i
                        ?
                    _.setAttribute("opacity", i * (t.opacity / 0.2))
                        :
                    i >= 0.8
                            ? _.setAttribute("opacity",t.opacity-(i-0.8)*(t.opacity/(1-0.8)))
                            :_.setAttribute("opacity",t.opacity)
                }
            );

            var scenarios={};

            scenarios.scenario_1=
            {
                actors:
                [
                    "actor_1",
                    "actor_2",
                    "actor_3",
                    "actor_4",
                    "actor_5",
                    "actor_6",
                    "actor_7",
                    "actor_8"
                ],
                tricks:
                [{
                    trick: "trick_1",
                    start:0,
                    end:1
                }],
                startAfter:0,
                duration:800,
                actorDelay:100,
                repeat:0,
                repeatDelay:0
            };

            var _reqAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.oRequestAnimationFrame,
            fnTick = function(t)
            {
                var r,a,i,e,n,o,s,c,m,f,d,k,w;

                for(c in actors)
                    actors[c]._tMatrix=[1,0,0,1,0,0];

                for(s in scenarios)
                    for(o=scenarios[s],m=t-o.startAfter,r=0,a=o.actors.length;a>r;r++)
                    {
                        if(i=actors[o.actors[r]],i&&i.node&&i._tMatrix)
                            for(f=0,m>=0&&(d=o.duration+o.repeatDelay,o.repeat>0&&m>d*o.repeat&&(f=1),f+=m%d/o.duration),e=0,n=o.tricks.length;n>e;e++)
                                k=o.tricks[e],w=(f-k.start)*(1/(k.end-k.start)),tricks[k.trick]&&tricks[k.trick](i,Math.max(0,Math.min(1,w)));m-=o.actorDelay
                    }

                for(c in actors)
                    i=actors[c],i&&i.node&&i._tMatrix&&i.node.setAttribute("transform","matrix("+i._tMatrix.join()+")");

                _reqAnimFrame(fnTick)
            };

            _reqAnimFrame(fnTick);
        }
    )()]]></script>
</svg>
```

I put that between `<my-app></my-app>` tag. But when I go to http://localhost:4200, the animation plays a little bit but then freezes.

Why is that happening? How can I use SVG for loading indicator on initial loading screen?

P.S. If I am using HTML + CSS animation it works correctly and animation plays during loading assets and scripts.

Comment: had the same problem with SVG (SMIL) animation. SMIL in general is not going to be supported going forward. So I would suggest to use CSS based animations for SVG. See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL

Comment: @SergeyRudenko thanks, i will check that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browser rendering page as **single-threaded**. And some of *CSS animated properties* could be freeze all animation when heavy js-script is executing.

[Here](http://www.phpied.com/css-animations-off-the-ui-thread/) more details about animation rendering.

If you are using SVG, animate it with `<animate />` tag