# SVG animation with animateTransform not working inside Angular's <app-root></app-root>

Tags: angular, svg

Is there any specific reason, why svg animations are working elsewhere but not in the main component template?

I usually have a css animated image for a loader and I wanted to try out an svg animation.

Example code:

```
<app-root>
  <div class="loader">
    <svg version="1.1" class="svg-loader" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
    y="0px" viewBox="0 0 80 80" xml:space="preserve">

      <path id="spinner" fill="#D43B11" d="M40,72C22.4,72,8,57.6,8,40C8,22.4,
        22.4,8,40,8c17.6,0,32,14.4,32,32c0,1.1-0.9,2-2,2
        s-2-0.9-2-2c0-15.4-12.6-28-28-28S12,24.6,12,40s12.6,
        28,28,28c1.1,0,2,0.9,2,2S41.1,72,40,72z">

      <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 40 40" to="360 40 40" dur="0.6s"
          repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</app-root>
```

**EDIT:**
I am testing it in Angular 5 and I was testing it in Angular 7.

Comment: what is class `loader` in top div element? trying remove it first and see if that is the problem

Comment: It's just a class to center my loader absolutely on the page. Already tried it without.

Comment: I remove this class and it works for me.

Comment: Ok, I should add, I am testing it in Angular 5 and I was testing it in Angular 7. The svg is displayed, but not animating/rotating.

Comment: Yes it seems that SVG animation is not running during initial load, I have made the same observation and changed to a static initial loading screen... seems the SVG is paused due to heavy JS operations

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076488/angular-freeze-svg-animation-on-initial-loading-screen

Comment: Well, the question is similar I would say. But I am using `animateTransform` to animate the SVG. I tried with `animate` as well. With no success. Of course, I can go back to using CSS keyframes. But that does not solve the problem, why it is not working inside the `app-root` element. It might really be a performance issue. Until somebody has a solution, I am using the old CSS approach.